# CONCATENATE using IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet I'm attempting to simplify and am coming across an issue.
What I need to do is combine three cells of strings together, but shorten one of them based on its value. What I'd like to do is this:

```
=CONCATENATE(G6,=IF(H6="BLACK","B",IF(H6="GALV","G","ERR")),I6)
```

which should be straightforward, yet Excel doesn't like that `IF` statement in the cell. It HAS to be contained into one cell, which makes this tough.

Is this possible?

Comment: You've got an extra =IF, it should be just IF.

Comment: To clarify what @Taosique said, your first `=IF` should just be `IF`.  The equal sign is only necessary as the first character to start a formula.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Should've said it properly. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(G6,IF(H6="BLACK","B",IF(H6="GALV","G","ERR")),I6)
```

There was small issue with your formula. You have used "**=**" operator inside formula which is invalid. Hence instead of **=IF** use just **IF**.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter version:

```
=G6&IF(OR(H6="black",H6="galv"),LEFT(H6),"ERR")&I6
```